# Scrolling UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to stop scrolling a `UICollectionView` always in the same place or section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe with KVO the [contentOffset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset) of the collection view. And if it's at the position (or range) where the scrolling should stop, set the contentOffset animated.